# Access contact in Windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to access the *contact details through C# Code for Windows Phone 8*.  So I was following up the example from the official page [How to access contact data for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh286416%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).  However this is suffering the following exception.

> An exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in
>   Microsoft.Phone.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Being new to this, I'm not able to find a solution to this problem.  Please shed some light on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the answer, it seems that we need to activate list of capabilities to be used within our app from

```
WMAppManifest.xml ---> Capabilities
```

Here by checking the **`ID_CAP_CONTACTS`** you can access the phone contacts in our app.

[image]